# RXJS combineLatest issue after upgarde 5 to 6

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs, migration, combinelatest

Service.ts file

Version 5 code:

```
return this.connectionListStoreService.connections$.pipe(
  combineLatest(this.isLoadPending$),
  filter(([connections, isPending]) => !isPending),
  map(([connections]) => connections),
  combineLatest(
    this.adapterStoreService.adapters$,
    this.applicationsStoreService.applications$
  ),
  map(([connections, adapters, applications]) => {
    if (!connections || !adapters || !applications) {
      return;
    }

    return connections
      .filter(connection => connection.source && connection.destination)
      .map((connection) => ({
        ...connection,
        source: {
          ...connection.source,
          adapter: adapters.find((item) => item.id === connection.source.appTypeId),
          application: applications.find((item) => item.id === connection.source.applicationId)
        },
        destination: {
          ...connection.destination,
          adapter: adapters.find((item) => item.id === connection.destination.appTypeId),
          application: applications.find((item) => item.id === connection.destination.applicationId)
        }
      }))
      .filter(({ source, destination }) =>
        source.application && source.adapter && destination.application && destination.adapter);
  })
);
```

Version 6 code:

```
return combineLatest([this.connectionListStoreService.connections$, this.isLoadPending$]).pipe(
  filter(([connections, isPending]) => !isPending),
  map(([connections]) => connections),
  combineLatest([this.adapterStoreService.adapters$, this.applicationsStoreService.applications$]),
  map(([connections, adapters, applications]) => {
    if (!connections || !adapters || !applications) {
      return;
    }

    return connections
      .filter(connection => connection.source && connection.destination)
      .map((connection) => ({
        ...connection,
        source: {
          ...connection.source,
          adapter: adapters.find((item) => item.id === connection.source.appTypeId),
          application: applications.find((item) => item.id === connection.source.applicationId)
        },
        destination: {
          ...connection.destination,
          adapter: adapters.find((item) => item.id === connection.destination.appTypeId),
          application: applications.find((item) => item.id === connection.destination.applicationId)
        }
      }))
      .filter(({ source, destination }) =>
        source.application && source.adapter && destination.application && destination.adapter);
  })
)
```

I modified this old code to new code some online guidelines. I am facing the issue in nested `combineLatest` in this function:

**Error:**

> @deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead
>
> Argument of type 'Observable<[AdapterModel[], ApplicationModel[]]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.
>
> Type 'Observable<[AdapterModel[], ApplicationModel[]]>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'.ts(2345)

Version of RXJS : "6.6.3",

Let me know the is there any additional information needed from my side. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're importing the correct `combineLatest`? You need to import one from `rxjs` and another one from `rxjs/operators`:

```
import { combineLatest as combineLatestWith } from 'rxjs';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

combineLatestWith([...]).pipe(
  ...
  combineLatest([...]),
)
```

I know, it's pretty confusing and it's about to [change again in RxJS 7](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-6).

Btw, there used to be official migration doc here that was removed from the repo's `master` branch for some reason: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried with your solution. import { combineLatest as combineLatestWith } from 'rxjs';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators'; - it is not working in 6 version.Because combineLatest 'rxjs/operators'; deprecated. And one more additional question can i use rxjs 7 because latest is 6. In 7 alpha,beta only

Comment: `combineLatest` from  'rxjs/operators' isn't deprecated. Only the variant without wrapping sources with array is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace the `combineLatest` operator with the [`withLatestFrom`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom), but looking at your stream, I'd make the following changes. I'd start with the `isPending$` observable and switch using `switchMap` operator and combine multiple observables using the `combineLatest` function.

Try the following

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.isPending$.pipe(
  filter(isPending => !isPending),
  switchMap(_ => 
    combineLatest(
      this.connectionListStoreService.connections$,
      this.adapterStoreService.adapters$,
      this.applicationsStoreService.applications$
    )
  ),
  map(([connections, adapters, applications]) => {
    ...
  })
);
```

Here the [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineLatest) function from RxJS v6+ is used instead of the old [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-combineLatest) operator.